# Splitting a long text in an equation

Tags: equations, text, multline, split

I want to split a long text in an equation. I also tried split and multiline but not working. Could you provide some suggestion ?

Comment: There are many posts about splitting equations here on TeX.SE, see also [this TUGboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-3/tb56down.pdf). If it doesn't help you, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I will delete the question as it has been asked in several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
How split these equation?
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f+g+h+j+gf+hg+gf+g & =\text{sdgdsgdsgdsgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgdgfgfgfgsfgfg}\\
& = \text{sdgdsgdsgdsgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgdgfgfgfgsfgfg}\\
& = \text{sdgdsgdsgdsgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgdgfgfgfgsfgfg}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The image does not correspond to the code.

Comment: You are right! I have used simultaneously papeeria and overleaf.

Comment: I think what is asked for is how to split a text which is longer than the remaining length on the line.

Comment: @Bernard Very sincerely few times, probably, do not quite understand what the user asks. If he accepted, perhaps I realized that was what he wanted. Sorry for my delay to your observation.

Comment: You're welcome. We do answer here on our spare time.

Comment: @Sebastiano Please don't suggest edits to 6 year old questions, that do not improve the question but just mark a few inline code words. While I am sure you intent to do something good, this does not add anything to the question and the only consequence will be that these questions, which already have perfectly fine answers, will be bumped on the active questions page.

Comment: @Sebastiano And please don't alter question to include thank you remarks, which the author did not write. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Comment: @Sebastiano http://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/113197 was the questions I was referring to in my previous comments.